# How can I send some text from popup to label in another class which is inherited from the Screen class?

Tags: python, kivy, popup

Sorry my english.
How can I send some text from popup to label in another class which is inherited from the Screen class?
I tried different options for accessing this object, but nothing happens.
It looks like text sends to another object, because  these objects has different memory adresses. I checked it.
Comment indicating the problem is in the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<Keyboard>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: text_input
        Button:
            text: 'Send text'
            on_release: root.send()

<Container>:
    label: label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: label
            text: 'Here must some be text from popup'
        Button:
            text: 'My popup'
            on_release: Factory.Keyboard().open()
        Button:
            text: 'Goto options'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Options'

<Options>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Back to time'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'Time'
""")

class Options(Screen):
    def show_kv(self, instance, value):
        self.manager.current = value


class Container(Screen):
    pass


class Keyboard(Popup):
    def send(self):
        try:
            time = self.text_input.text
        except:
            time = ''
        # Here is some problem
        Container().label.text = time  # Nothing happens
        self.dismiss()


class KivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Container(name='Time'))
        sm.add_widget(Options(name='Options'))
        sm.current = "Time"
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
Container().label.text = time
```

is creating a new instance of `Container`, and sets the `text` of a `Label` in that new instance. However, that instance of `Container` is not the one that appears in your GUI. You must access the instance that is actually in your GUI. You can do that using the `get_screen()` method of the `ScreenManager` that is the root of your GUI. Like this:

```
    container_instance = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('Time')
    container_instance.label.text = time
```